# How to write Event hooks in locust for response times of Individual requests

Tags: python, event-handling, locust

I am planning to test my web server for performance using locust, 
The problem with the below code is that it is only giving me the average times

My basic code is as follows

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, events, web
def index(l):
        l.client.get("/")

def stats(l):
        l.client.get("/stats/requests")

class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
       tasks = [index,stats]

class MyLocust(HttpLocust):
    host = "http://127.0.0.1:8089"
    min_wait = 2000
    max_wait = 5000
    task_set = MyTaskSet
    request_success_stats = [list()]
    request_fail_stats = [list()]

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLocust, self).__init__()
        locust.events.request_success += self.hook_request_success
        locust.events.request_failure += self.hook_request_fail
        locust.events.quitting += self.hook_locust_quit

    def hook_request_success(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length):
            self.request_success_stats.append([name, request_type, response_time, response_length])

    def hook_request_fail(self, request_type, name, response_time, exception):
        self.request_fail_stats.append([name, request_type, response_time, exception])

    def hook_locust_quit(self):
        self.save_success_stats()

    def save_success_stats(self):
        import csv
        with open('success_req_stats.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                for value in self.request_success_stats:
                    writer.writerow(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is measuring the actual response times.

The catch here is that if the payload has multiple URI's then the response time for each of them will be recorded, which has to be in turn sorted/the duplicates removed while recording the results